# Pairs plot by row split in R

Tags: r, scatter-plot

How can I create a scatter plot using pairs by splitting the data(200 rows)into 2 by row in two diff colors. I tried,

```
pairs(sbn[1:100,],col = "red",pch = 3)
```

I didn't know how to add a different color for the remaining 100 rows.

Answer (score 0):

You can pass a vector specifying the colors to the pairs function:

```
seed(123)
df = data.frame(x = runif(200), y = runif(200))

dfcol = vector()
dfcol[1:100] = "red"
dfcol[101:200] = "blue"

pairs(df, col = dfcol)
```

Which gives the following output:
[image]